# Using angular I want to input two files with same name but different file extension by doing the input of just one

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
<input #fileInput hidden="true" type="file" accept="*" (onChange)="uploadFile($event)"/>
```

and in my component.ts

```
uploadFile(fileEvent){}
```

Comment: try to use `multiple` attribute in your input and check.


    <input #fileInput hidden="true" type="file" accept="*" (onChange)="uploadFile($event)" multiple/>

Comment: @FarhatZaman I don't want to use multiple, I want to restrict the user to select only one file,  like abc.doc then our code should check and pick the abc.pdf along with abc.doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript will not allow you to read a file that was not selected through file selector for security reasons. It would be a major security breach if you entered a web page and it could read randomly files in your system.